# Dynamic Accordion-group not closing others when header clicked

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

We have a working Accordion Group that is dynamically loaded, with the subitem content populated when the headers are clicked.

It all works, except that we don't seem to be able to get other items to close when the next item is clicked.

We have `close-others="true"` and the data structure is properly updating on the `ng-click` item.

Any help?

Here's the html

```
<accordion close-others="true" class="accordion">
    <accordion-group heading="Team {{$index + 1}}" 
      ng-click="TabAction(tab.TeamRef, $index)" 
      ng-repeat="tab in Tabs" is-open="tab.IsOpen">
        <div ng-repeat="t in tab.Team track by $index" 
           class="mf-custom-list-item">
        </div>
    </div>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

And here's the `On Click` event that manages the `tab.IsOpen` value

```
$scope.TabAction = function (teamref, indx) {
    let TabIndex = $scope.TabIndex;
    if ($scope.Tabs[TabIndex].IsOpen && (TabIndex = indx)) {
        $scope.Tabs[TabIndex].IsOpen = false;
    } else {
        // Only open a tab if it is different to that already open
        $scope.Tabs[indx].IsOpen     = true;
        $scope.Tabs[TabIndex].IsOpen = false;
        BidService.LoadBidTeam(teamref, indx, $scope);
    }
    $scope.TabIndex                              = indx;
    $rootScope.app.appstate.Bid.Summary.TabIndex = indx;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can do like this

```
   $scope.TabAction = function (teamref, indx) {
        //close all tabs first
        for(var i = 0, l = $scope.Tabs.length; i < l; i++){
           $scope.Tabs[i].IsOpen = false;
        }
        let TabIndex = $scope.TabIndex;

        $scope.Tabs[indx].IsOpen     = true;

        BidService.LoadBidTeam(teamref, indx, $scope);

        $scope.TabIndex                              = indx;
        $rootScope.app.appstate.Bid.Summary.TabIndex = indx;
    };
```

Comment: That's also not working. Again the settings of IsOpen are responding correctly, but it appears that the front end (html) isn't responding to IsOpen changing